# Which one of these three versions is grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, comparative-constructions

> Arguably no other writer gave so much attention to detail as **X did.**

> Arguably no other writer gave so much attention to detail as **X.**

> Arguably no other writer gave so much attention to detail as **did X.**

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct? Please cite the reason alongside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean "so much" rather than "some much".

With that emendation, all are fine. 3 is considerably more formal than the others.

Comment: That's right. Sorry about the typo. Why is the first one correct though? Do all three versions use _ellipsis_? And how is "more formality" of one version decided over others? @Colin Fine.

Comment: Why should the first one not be? I suspect you are working from an old-fashioned grammar book that tells you you have to invert the subject and verb/auxiliary in this construction. That is what I mean by "more formal": the traditional prescriptive grammarians say "invert" so no 3 is what you do if you are writing for prescriptive grammarians. Ordinary people talking ordinary English ignore the prescriptive grammarians (as they always have) and say 1 or 2.